# Altering session permanently

Tags: oracle, session, timestamp, oracle-sqldeveloper, alter

Is it possible to alter the session permanently even after i close my oracle sql developer?

An example of the statement that i want to alter:

```
Alter Session Set Nls_Timestamp_Tz_Format='HH24:MI TZR';
```

The above statement only allow me to alter the current session and not making it permanently.

Thanks

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on serverfault.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to change the default value for SQL Developer, you can do that in the SQL Developer settings.  In SQL Developer 3.1 (the same settings exist in earlier versions though the navigation may be slightly different), Tools | Preferences | Database | NLS allows you to specify a Timestamp Format and a Timestamp TZ Format.  SQL Developer will then automatically issue the appropriate `ALTER SESSION` commands for you whenever it creates a new session.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. It's very clear cut. I know that sql developer can change our own settings. But if i grant the table to other users, they will not have the same configuration. Is there any sample method on configuring it?

Comment: @user976050 - No.  Other users will use other clients.  Other clients will take their NLS settings from other places.  Other users may have different NLS preferences.  If you want to present a particular string representation of a field to other users, create a view that does an explicit `TO_CHAR` with the specified format mask and grant the users access to the view.

Comment: Ok that's what i have done for display all the different timezones in differnt table. i was just thinking if there is any easier way to do like making it permanent. Thanks for your clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this in the [initialization parameter file](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams148.htm) to affect the database globally.

Comment: The NLS settings in the database are overruled by the settings on the client so that's not going to work.  There are very few cases where the database's default NLS settings are actually used.

Answer (score 0):

Initialization parameters such as `Nls_Timestamp_Tz_Format` can be set up from three sources:

- In a session using the `ALTER SESSION SET` statement
- In client side parameter file `init.ora`
- In server side parameter file `spfile`

Comment: May i know how can i alter the 'init.ora' to set it default?

Comment: The init.ora and spfile are both server-side parameter files.  Any given database instance can be started either with an init.ora file or with a spfile but not both.  NLS settings are controlled by the client and are controlled differently for different client applications.  Something like SQL*Plus will derive the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT` from the `NLS_LANG` which is set either as an environment variable or in the registry.  Other applications will derive the values from elsewhere.

Comment: so in conclusion, there is no way to edit the nls settings for other client even I grant privilege to them? Thanks

Comment: `init.ora` is a text file typically located at `$ORACLE_HOME/database`. You can edit it with any text editor add lines like `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.FF TZH:TZM'`

Comment: `init.ora` and spfile are both located in the database server. But they operate at different levels. first one is client side and the second is server side. Ref: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SPFILE

Comment: @Raihan, init.ora and spfile are both server-side files as Justin stated. One or the other is read on startup by the database to set instance parameters. Most commonly nowadays the spfile is used and is the preferred method, because you can modify many instance parameters and save the settings in the spfile. Neither file is useful for client processes.

Comment: Technically, the init.ora is not *necessarily* a server-side file!  In most cases, yes, the init.ora is on the server, and one logs into the server and starts the database, either with the init.ora inthe default place, or via the 'PFILE=' option of the STARTUP command in SQL*Plus.  However, it's possible to have the init.ora on a client machine, do a remote connection via SYSDBA, and specify the local, client side init.ora, and to start the remote server.

Answer (score 0):

To set default permanently in the db, from the database:-

```
alter system ... scope=spfile;
```

then as SYS (so you may need to talk to a DBA), and obviously at an appropriate time! -

```
shutdown;
startup;
```

(I know the spfile has been mentioned, but it can all be done from the sqlplus cmdline, at least in 11g.)